# Django Channels failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am stuck in this error,I have tried to change many things to fix but still getting error:

**(index):42 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/user2/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

Here's below my code:

**Client Side:**

```
var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
    var formdata=$("#form");
    var input_val=$("#id_messages");
    var chatHolder=$("#chat-items");
    loc=window.location;  // get the addresses
    console.log(window.location);

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" +'127.0.0.1:8000' +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');
    console.log(chatSocket);


    // client side receives the message
    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
     console.log("message",e)
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    chatSocket.onopen = function(e){
        console.log("open",e);
        formdata.submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var msgText=input_val.val();
            var finalData={
                'message':msgText
            };
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData));
            formdata[0].reset()
        })
    };

    chatSocket.onmessage=function(e){
        var chatdata=JSON.parse(e.data);

      chatHolder.append("<li>"+chatdata.message+ " via "+ chatdata.username +"</li>")
    };


    chatSocket.onerror= function(e){
        console.log("error",e)
    };
```

**Consumer.py**:

```
 def __init__(self, scope):
        super().__init__(scope)
        self.chat_room=""

    async def websocket_connect(self,event):
        me=await self.get_user("user")
        other_user="user2" # let pass static value for now for user 2
        thread_obj=await self.get_thread(me,other_user)
        chat_room=f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room=chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
        print(thread_obj)
        #await asyncio.sleep(10)

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected",event)

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        front_text=event.get('text',None)

        if front_text is not None:
            load_dict_data=json.loads(front_text)
            msg=load_dict_data.get('message')
            user=self.scope['user']
            username="default"

            if user.is_authenticated:
                username=user.username

            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username
            }
            # broadcast the message
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text":json.dumps(myResponse)

                }
            )

# message to be sent
    async def chat_message(self,event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text']

        })

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self,user,other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user,other_username)[0]

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self,username):
        Muser=User.objects.get(username=username)
        return Muser
```

**Settings.py:**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "Frames.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    "default":{
      "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
      "CONFIG": {
                "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
            },
    },
}
```

**routing.py**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

The socket url where the request sent is correct,but the connections always failed.How can I fix the problem,is there some sort of redis problem?

Comment: Why are some of your methods inside `__init__()`?

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue, and it turns out it was due to the bad connection between django and redis. Try using something else for the Channel Layer.

```py
ASGI_APPLICATION = "Frames.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    }
}
```

source: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html?highlight=channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer#in-memory-channel-layer

Warning: Not for Production Use.

If this fixes it, you will at least know that your issue is with redis connection.

(edit): Try upgrading your redis to v5 if haven't

Answer (score 1):

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
},
'CONFIG': {
        "hosts": [('redis',6379)],
    },
```

}

To storage you should it, it worked on me